# 'object' does not contain a definition for 'NewRow' and no extension method 'NewRow' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

Tags: c#

i got error in Rows .Error is Viewstate["dt"] used as object and Rows Doesn't contain definition for object

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string Row = e.RowIndex.ToString();        
    DataRow dtrow = default(DataRow);
    dtrow = ViewState["dt"].Rows[Row];
    ViewState["dt"].Rows.Remove(dtrow);
    GridView1.DataSource = ViewState["dt"];
    GridView1.DataBind();
    CalculateItemNetAmount();
}
```

Comment: Is that the wrong code? I dont see a call to ``NewRow``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cast your `ViewState["dt"]` into a `DataTable` first.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    string Row = e.RowIndex.ToString();        
    DataRow dtrow = default(DataRow);
    var dataTable = (DataTable)ViewState["dt"];
    dtrow = dataTable .Rows[Row];
    dataTable.Rows.Remove(dtrow);
    GridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    CalculateItemNetAmount();
}
```

Comment: @dibyanshuaryan Welcome. Also, please don't forget to mark the correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

That's cause `ViewState["dt"]` is of type `object`. You need to cast it to proper type, in your case `DataTable` before accessing it's `Rows` property like

```
((DataTable)ViewState["dt"]).Rows[Row];
```